# How to estimate missing values by using Rubins Rules over multiple imputed datasets in python

Tags: python, missing-data, imputation

I am able to impute missing data easily in Python as there are plenty of tools to do so (MiceForest, Autoimpute etc), however once I have the several imputed datasets and I have ran my analysis on them, I want to pool the results from the analysis. There seems to be lots of packages in R that can do this but not very many in Python? Especially for analysis that isn't either linear regression or decisions tree. Can anyone suggest a way of pooling over the results in python using Rubin's Rules?

Comment: there is a `R` package in python which you can use, however you can always develop it yourself. I am doing something like this and I'll mention it here in a week or two.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, you can it manually for coef and std (this is in R but easy to convert to python)

```
#V - the within variance. We square the extracted standard errors and take colMeans
V <- colMeans(ses.amelia^2)
# We calculate the between variance
# the sweep function takes 4 arguments - 1. the object to be operated on (a matrix )
# 2. an indicator: 1 = rowwise, 2 = columnwise
# 3. a vector with the same number of columns or rows (depending
# on the previous parameter)
# 4. a function. In this case subtraction
B <- ((1/(5-1)) *colSums((sweep(coefs.amelia,2,coefmeans,"-"))^2))
#Calculating the total variance
T <- V+ (1 + 1/5) *B
#Square rooting gives the pooled variance
SEt <- sqrt(T)
#Show the output
SEt
`
```

however not sure how this is done for P values or if there is an easier way